# Create Sitecore Form datasource token

Tags: sitecore-forms

I want to use Sitecore Form folder as my datasource so that I can pull Sitecore Forms based on my different Site regions.

When I use SXA form rendering, I want an option to select particular forms folder as a root for datasource selection. Do we have custom token for Sitecore form?

Comment: Please provide some more information. When you use form rendering, do you want an option to select forms folder as datasource?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: And how do you plan to use this folder afterwards ? Basically it is simple to change datasource location/template in form rendering. But it is not ideal. It seems you may need a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some code samples that you can try to achieve this. You should need to use a custom rendering datasource for this and the pipeline that you need to patch is the `getRenderingDatasource`.

Create a processor that will get your rendering datasource and write a code to get the results on the basis of your condition and add the items. Here is the sample code.

```
public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(args, "args");

    string text = args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"]; //Get the value from the field
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        if (text.StartsWith("query:") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.ContextItemPath))
        {
            var contextItem = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(args.ContextItemPath);

            if (contextItem != null)
            {
                text = text.Remove(0, 6); //remove the query:
                //Execute the query or write the code to get the items on the basis of your condition. 
                var item = contextItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(text); 

                if (item != null)
                {
                    args.DatasourceRoots.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this to patch into config.

```
<getRenderingDatasource>
    <processor type="YourNamespaceHere, YourAssemblyName"
    patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.GetRenderingDatasource.GetDatasourceLocation, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
</getRenderingDatasource>
```

For more reference: https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/sitecore-custom-rendering-datasource/

Hope this helps and give you some idea to implement.